# How can I change the x axis labels in this ggplot to their pi symbols?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I want the x axis labels of this graph to be "0", "π/2", "π", "3/2*π", "2*π"

I don't want them to be the actual values of 0, 1.57. 3.14.. etc.

But if i try to do something like `labels  = c(seq(0, 2*pi, pi/2))` it makes a crazy graph with no pi values in the x axis.

```
x <- seq(0,2*pi, 0.01)
y <- sin(x)

sin(pi)

ggplot() +

  geom_line(aes(x,y)) +

  scale_x_continuous(breaks  = c(seq(0, 2*pi, pi/2))) +

  theme_bw()
```

Is there some other function that will change the x axis labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `labels=` argument to your x scale. Here I have used the unicode symbol for pi, `\u03C0` for portability:

```r
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(0,2*pi, 0.01)
y <- sin(x)

ggplot() +
 geom_line(aes(x,y)) +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks  = c(seq(0, 2*pi, pi/2)), 
                    labels = c("0", "\u03c0/2", "\u03c0", "3/2*\u03c0", "2*\u03c0")) +
 theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: so is "\u03c0/" just the code for the "pi" symbol for ggplot?

Comment: @dftag no, it might work on your system by just having π characters in the strings, but in R you can access most unicode characters by doing a `\u` followed by the 4-digit unicode value. This is not unique to ggplot or even R. Unicode is a global standard for encoding extended character sets. See what happens in R when you type `"\u03c0"` (quotes included) in the console.

Comment: It worked and did what I wanted it to do. Thank you for your answer! I didn't know that unicode existed and it's good to know now that it does.