# How can I replace numbers on an axis with symbols in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, unicode

I'm making a scatter plot and want to replace the numbers of the y axis with symbols. Specifically, I want to swap 20 for a minus symbol and 0 with a plus symbol.

[image]

I've had a look at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964458/how-can-i-change-the-x-axis-labels-in-this-ggplot-to-their-pi-symbols) but the way I create the y axis is a bit different.

Thanks.

Here's my plotting code:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(exampledf, aes(x = male_diff, y = index, color = as.factor(expt_in_ms))) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha = 0.5, size = 3)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = female_diff),alpha = 0.8, shape =24, size = 5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:nrow(exampledf), labels = exampledf$nloci) +
  xlab("difference in proportion") +
  ylab("correlation") +
  geom_vline(
    xintercept = 0,
    color = 'black',
    linetype = 'dashed',
    alpha = .5
  ) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(text = element_text(size = 12)) + guides(alpha=FALSE) + guides(size=FALSE) +
  guides(shape = FALSE) + guides(color = FALSE)
```

Here's the data set called `exampledf` in the plotting code:

```
structure(list(male_diff = c(0.4668, -0.03299, 0.702, -0.11544, 
0.689, 0.511, -0.0725, -0.12844, -0.0827, 0.6515, -0.01077, 0.006, 
0.0041, -0.00856, 0.4181, -0.02765), female_diff = c(-0.459, 
0.022, -0.155, 0.00800000000000001, -0.156, -0.326, -0.0224, 
0.00700000000000001, 0.0399999999999999, 0.2182, -0.08458, 0.8844, 
-0.8459, 0.122, -0.506, 0.03), expt_in_ms = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), nloci = c(0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 
0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 20), index = 1:16), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested `gsub()` in the `labels` argument. Here, `\u2212` is the unicode minus symbol, but you can use a hyphen too. The regex bit `^` indicates 'starts with', whereas `$` indicates 'ends with', so `^0$` should match exact 0s.

```r
library(tidyverse)

exampledf <- structure(
  list(male_diff = c(0.4668, -0.03299, 0.702, -0.11544, 0.689, 0.511, -0.0725, 
                     -0.12844, -0.0827, 0.6515, -0.01077, 0.006, 0.0041, 
                     -0.00856, 0.4181, -0.02765), 
       female_diff = c(-0.459, 0.022, -0.155, 0.00800000000000001, -0.156, 
                       -0.326, -0.0224, 0.00700000000000001, 0.0399999999999999,
                       0.2182, -0.08458, 0.8844, -0.8459, 0.122, -0.506, 0.03), 
       expt_in_ms = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
       nloci = c(0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 20), 
       index = 1:16), 
  row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

ggplot(exampledf, aes(x = male_diff, y = index, color = as.factor(expt_in_ms))) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha = 0.5, size = 3)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = female_diff),alpha = 0.8, shape =24, size = 5) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = 1:nrow(exampledf), 
    labels = gsub("^0$", "+", gsub("^20$", "\u2212", exampledf$nloci))
  ) +
  xlab("difference in proportion") +
  ylab("correlation") +
  geom_vline(
    xintercept = 0,
    color = 'black',
    linetype = 'dashed',
    alpha = .5
  ) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  guides(alpha="none", size = "none", shape = "none", color = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: is `labels = factor(exampledf$nloci, labels=c("-", "+"))` enough ... maybe not as nice a symbol

Comment: Thanks, I had just tried creating a vector with the symbols (`symbols <- c("+","\u2013","+","\u2013","+", "+", "+", "\u2013", "\u2013", "\u2013", "+", "\u2013", "+", "\u2013", "+", "\u2013")`) but your response is much safer.

Comment: @user20650 the labels are in the wrong order, but in this case you could use that too, assuming that the only two numbers are 0 and 20.

Comment: yes. But on viewing `U2212` is much better typeset

Comment: `\u2212` is designed to be used in combination with the `+` symbol. The horizontal stripes in both symbols have the same length. I'm not a typographer though and probably any reader will interpret hyphens, en- and em-dashes as minus signs.